# IIS 7.5 " web service does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1."

Tags: iis-7.5, wcf, wsdl

I am trying to migrate a site from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5.

When the page loads, I receive the error as shown in the screenshot below. Even while files are identical on the IIS 6 server (where this works), the error complains that `"This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace."`

In my searches, I have found that this may have something to do with WSDL.

Apologies for being vague, but if someone could point me in the general direction of an answer I can probably take it from there.

[image: login_aspx screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. Update the namespace of your web service (that is, in the source code.), to an actual (and correct) one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. While I agree that the error seems straightforward, I was concerned because this problem only occurs on IIS 7.5. That led me to believe that something must be amiss with regards to the server configuration. I will pass this on to the devs and see what they find.